# Should I store data as a variable in javascript or in a text file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a webpage, and I want it to display a random text. Suppose I have around 1000 sentences (for example), and I want to select a random sentence from the list.

Which would be a better way: to store all these sentences in a `javascript array` or to store them in a text file, and then use `javascript` to read a line from the file?

Essentially, how does this impact the performance? And the 1000 lines are just for example, I want to know how the general approach should be for increasing variable size.

The desired result is that the webpage should load fast, and should not be computationally heavy on the `client side`.

Note that the page is static and the `sentences` are immutable and won't change over the course of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question:**

What approach is the best among these 2 options?

**Option 1:** 1000 sentences inside javascript array variable

**Vs.**

**Option 2:** 1000 sentences served in a separate text file (json format assumed)'

---

**Answer:**

The 3 major aspects that impact the performance of a web app are:

1. Number of network calls between browser and server
2. Amount of data downloaded from server
3. Amount of memory consumed by Javascript running on browser

Performance can be enhanced by minimizing and balancing the above aspects.

Loading 1000 sentences into one array variable will reduce the number of network calls.
Therefore, it is a very good option to improve performance, 
as long as the following conditions are true:

1. Total size of the 1000 sentences is small (only up to several KB)
2. There is no security risk in showing full data to user (if all data is kept in variable, then the user can see all sentences by opening developer console).

If the sentences are big in size, or if the requirement is to hide the remaining 999 sentences from user, then the idea of keeping those in a separate json file on server and serving only one of the sentences based on random value is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about performance, storing them in an array is always going to be a huge boost in performance than storing them in a file and reading them which comes with additional cost.

Just imagine doing this for getting your variables.(I'm assuming it's kept in your local machine and there's no network call involved) **vs** keeping the variables in-memory

```
  var myFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myFile.open("GET", file, false);
    myFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(myFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(myFile.status === 200 || myFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = myFile.responseText;
                //Finally You get it Here. Phew!!!
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also consider storing in `localstorage` as the variable size grows significantly. That'd perform better than the text file. However, you need to keep in mind, you can not directly store, `objects` and `array` in `localstorage`. You'll need to `strigify` and and store it and again while retrieving them, you'll need to parse them, which is at additional cost.

Comment: I second Rahul. Performance-wise, hardcoding the sentences in an array will yield a fastest load.

Answer (score 2):

**There can be one approach to this:**

You can use JS arrays to store all sentences in the browser's local storage, instead of storing it a file and repeatedly reading it.

Have a look to this on how to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)